# ASP.NET MVC : Empty Collection in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi,
I'am pretty new in ASP.NET MVC, and I have some problem.

I make some program that searching product in data base, if click 
button "end", program show me list of my previously searched products.**

This is my code from controler:

```
private ProductManager pm = new ProductManager();
private PointOfSaleContext db = new PointOfSaleContext();



public ActionResult Detail(SearchProduct productCode)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
               //searching product in data base
                var searchingProduct = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == productCode.Code).Single();
                int id = searchingProduct.ProductId; 

                //add searched product to model
                SingleProduct product = new SingleProduct();
                product.product = searchingProduct;

               //I send product Id to ProductManager method
                pm.AddToList(id);

                return View(product); 
            }
        }

   public ActionResult List()
   {
        //object of model
       AllItems all = new AllItems();

      //
       all.productList = pm.list;
       return View(all);
   }
```

This is my class, where I created Product list

```
public class ProductManager
    {
        private PointOfSaleContext db = new PointOfSaleContext();
        public List<product> list;

        public ProductManager()
        { 
            list = new List<product>();

        }
        public void AddToList(int id) 
        {
            var product = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == id).SingleOrDefault();
            list.Add(product);

        }        
    }
```

View of controller List:

```
@model PointOfSale.ViewModel.AllItems

<ul>

    @foreach (var p in  Model.productList)
    {
       <li> @p.ProductName <li>
    }
</ul>
```

My ViewModel:

```
 public class AllItems
    {
        public List<Product> productList { get; set; }
    }
    public class SingleProduct
    {
        public Product product;
    }
```

Problem is those, that I can't read data from ICollection in AddToList View.
More precisely- Model in View List is empty and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you sure the right view is being loaded? What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: Yes, after I was clicking go to view, I have been moved to right view.

Comment: Every time you load a controller action, a new `ProductManager` is instantiated. You need to come up with a new design that uses the database directly.

Comment: The only way that might work is to use static ProductManager. But that is a bad architecture.